# Best way to learn Apex coding for begginer to salesforce

Tags: apex

I am new to salesforce. I dont have coding background. Please let me know bst way to learn apex coding?

Answer (score 6):

Some of the things that can get you started in no time:

- Read the [Apex Developer's Guide](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm)
- Visit [developer.force.com](http://developer.force.com)
- Get on [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead)
- Get your own developer org and start experimenting

Answer (score 4):

In addition to some of the excellent resources others have posted, you may want to check out the following:

- [From Admin to Developer: Learning to Code on Force.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlggcSeXmFc) at Dreamforce 2014
- [Get Started with Apex Code for Admins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Azb31kE31ZA) presentation at Dreamforce 2013
- [Apex for Admins: Get Started with Apex in 30 Minutes!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okVqV-D7h0g) Salesforce webinar
- [Beginner tutorials on SFDC99.com](http://www.sfdc99.com/beginner-tutorials/) (no coding experience required)
- [How buying a major appliance can help you understand Object-Oriented Programming](http://womencodeheroes.com/2014/12/oop-terminology-explained-classes-variables-methods-objects/), by Kieren Jameson

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking courses Java for beginners. This will help you learn how to code in general. Just try to write apps which process list of integers, like to find min or max, sorting, working with string, etc.

1. Java and Apex have similar syntax (actually, the same).
2. It's faster to learn using Java, because code is processed on your machine without sending it to SFDC's server and back.
3. After you had basic understanding of how to code in Java, there will be no problem to code in Salesforce, using Apex.

Before Salesforce, I coded in C#, Java, PHP... It was no problem to start coding in Apex at all.